# How to redirect login page to dashboard using ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-loadable

I want when I submit the email and the password to login, it will be redirected to the dashboard, my code is below :

```
     handleClick(event){
    
    var payload={
      "email":this.state.email,
        "password":this.state.password
    }
    axios({
          method: 'post',
          url: '/app/login/',
          data: payload,
          withCredentials: true,
          headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
          }
        })
   
   .then(function (response) {
     console.log(response);
     if(response.data.code == 200){
          response.redirect('http://localhost:5000/#/dashboard');

     }
     else if(response.data.code == 204){
       swal("Erreur !", "Vérifiez vos champs SVP !", "error");
      
     }
     else{
       swal("Erreur !", "Username inexistant !", "error");
      
     }
   })
  }
```

My route :

```
import React from 'react';
import Loadable from 'react-loadable'
const Dashboard = Loadable({
  loader: () =>
    import ('./views/Dashboard'),
  loading: Loading,
});
const routes = [
{ path: '/dashboard', name: 'Dashboard', component: Dashboard }]
```

When I run it, I get :
[image]

How can I fix that please ?

Comment: which react router you;re using?

Comment: please share your code of component and router

Comment: @SakhiMansoor react-loadable

Comment: I mean for navigation how are you doing routing ? please share your code

Comment: @SakhiMansoor I edit my post

Comment: Please share your complete component

Comment: @SakhiMansoor https://codeshare.io/5OZbdW

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179330/discussion-between-codelover-and-sakhi-mansoor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `redirect` method in axios response object.
To handle this you might workout with your router which you use.

### Example:

`router.push({ path: '/dashboard' })`
Like this...

### Edited:

In case you using `react-router`: try to extract `history` from component props, like this:

```
this.props.history.push('/dashboard')
```

Comment: I get :  `×
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5_react_router__.a.push is not a function`

Comment: I get `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'props' of undefined` I edit my post

Answer (score 2):

use `withRouter` to access history props in your component:

here is working example : https://codeshare.io/5OZbdW